# ステータスバーの表示を持続させたい

Tags: emeditor

フィルターツールバーで指定する文字列に一致する行のみを表示すると、ステータスバーの左のほうに

52行が一致しました。（6スレッド, 0.031秒）

などと表示されますが、しばらくすると何かの拍子に消えてしまいます。

これを持続して表示する方法はありますか。
また、この文字列をコピーする方法はありますか。

置換後の場合も

4個置換されました（6スレッド, 0.016秒）

などと表示されますが、これも同様にできればありがたいです。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ステータス バーで右クリックして表示されるメニューから [コピー] を選択すれば、コピーできます。
[何かの拍子に消える] というのは、おそらく、マウス ポインタを動かしていて、URL などの上に移動すると、その時点で、書き換わるためではないかと思います。マウスを動かさなければ、通常は消えることはないと思います。

Comment: 早速のお返事、ありがとうございます。いずれもその通りで、コピーもできました。マウスポインタがURLの上に移動してもステータスバーが書き換わらないようにする（「https://…… を開く」と表示させないようにする）方法はありますか。

Comment: 残念ながら、現在のバージョンでは、マウスポインタがURLの上に移動してもステータスバーが書き換わらないようにする、という方法はないです。

Comment: 「すべての設定のプロパティ」の「アクティブな文字列」でURIのチェックを外せばステータスバーはそのまま表示されるようになりました。ありがとうございました。